# Reasoning behind GPS time week number?

Tags: gps

So the GPS Week Number rollover has been all over the news lately. I don't really know anything about GPS, but my first thought upon reading up on this topic was: **why use a week-based format in the first place?**

It seems like it would have been much more intuitive to use, say, the number of seconds since the GPS epoch. I realize that there's some degree of arbitrariness to all formats, and that there's usually some historical baggage that plays in, but counting *weeks* seems like a very unusual choice even then.

Is there some practical or historical reason for this design?

Comment: "Why" is opion based but that's how it has been designed. http://www.geokniga.org/bookfiles/geokniga-seeber-g-satellite-geodesy-2003.pdf in chapter 7.1.5.3 Computation of Satellite Time and Satellite Coordinates.

Comment: @ahmadhanb, this doesn't seem to be a 'general IT' question, and GPS data / metadata should be clearly a GIS question.

Comment: Indeed, I chose to ask this question on the GIS Stack Exchange specifically because it concerns the GPS Navigation Message format. I'm a software developer myself, but that doesn't mean I have any insight into the design of this particular technology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A satellite's signals (radio waves) must pass through many atmospheric interference (e.g., tropospheric and ionospheric) to reach a GPS receiver on earth, so the messages encoded in the signal must be as compact as possible. One such message is the *Navigation Message*, transmitted as five 300-bit sub-frames at 50 bits/sec. The Navigation Message needed to pack a lot of information in 1500 bits so every bit counts. Expressing date and time as TOW only requires 19 bits, instead of the usual 32 (e.g., Windows OS) or 64-bit (e.g., Unix OS).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Navigation_message